# object detection with neural networks: merge classes or not?

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection

When using methods such as Faster R-CNN or Yolo for object detection,
does it make sense to cluster visually dissimilar objects to reduce the number of classes?
Let's make up an artificial example: Let's say all the chairs and scissors in the world are by manufacturer A and all the shoes and computers are by manufacturer B. I want to detect objects by manufacturers A and B. Is it better to have two classes A and B and train with them,
or to have 4 classes Chair, Scissors, Shoe, Computer (and then combine the shoes and computers to B in after processing)?
I was thinking especially a case where there are many, say, a hundred or more classes?